# Discord js deafening an user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hello I'm trying to deafen a particular person in discord but I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: message.setDeaf is not a function

The discord js docs state that you should deafen members like this.

> .setDeaf(deaf)
>
> Deafen/undeafen a user.

I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error, below is my code;

```
var Discord  = require("discord.js");
var client = new Discord.Client();
var user = "30898500862111287"

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.content === '$deafen') {
    message.setDeaf(user);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you connected the Client to a Bot User?

Comment: Why are you using `setDeaf` on `message`? I would think it should be something like `user.setDeaf(true|false)`? (In that case, `user` would need to be the actual user object, and not just an ID). Notice that `deaf` in the docs is a Boolean: https://discord.js.org/?_sm_au_=irVJ1Zb7fnGs56LG#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setDeaf

Answer (score 2):

`setDeaf()` is a function derived from `GuildMember`, not `Message`. Since `Message` does not contain a function called `setDeaf()`, it gave you that error.

In order to get `GuildMember`, which is the user you want to deafen/undeafen, you can first get the `user` from the `Message`, in your case, it will be `message.author`, which will return the `user` who sent that message.

Now, on `Guild`, there is a `FetchMember()` function that returns a `GuildMember` datatype. For that function's argument, all you have to do is just to put in your `user` that you want to target.
(Your `Guild` will of course be the guild where the message is in! `Message.Guild` should do the trick.)

Last step is just to deafen/undeafen the user.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `setDeaf()` on a `Message` and not a `GuildMember` (`SetDeaf()` is a `GuildMember` method).

Additionally, you're passing an unexisting value `user` to `setDeaf()`. I'm guessing you were trying to pass the `message.author`, but `setDeaf()` takes a boolean and an optional reason string, not a `User`.

You can achieve what you're looking for with this:

```
if(message.content == "$deafen")
     message.member.setDeaf(true);
```

Alternatively, add a reason:

```
if(message.content == "$deafen")
     message.member.setDeaf(true, "reason");
```

*References:*
[*Message Object*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member)
[*GuildMember Object*](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot invoke a Server Deaf on Message. You can do it on Guild_Member.

If you want to get the first mentioned member:

```js
let mMember = message.mentions.members.first()

mMember.setDeaf(true)
```

You can also invoke it on the message_author with a member property.

```js
message.member.setDeaf(true)
```

But you cannot set a Server Deaf on a Message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they've changed the code for this a little bit, instead of:

```
member.setDeaf(true);
```

You now use:

```
member.voice.setDeaf(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is solution:

```
            const user = message.mentions.members.first()
        if(!args[1]) {
            message.channel.send('send me a user to mute in voice')
        } else {
            user.voice.setDeaf(true, `${args[2]}`)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you may only deafen guild members a useful approach could be getting the guild member.

You pass the set deaf an id, this would in short throw a logic error because you passed an invalid argument type.

The following should achieve what you were going for.

```js
var Discord  = require("discord.js");
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("YOUR GUILD ID");
const user = guild.members.cache.get("30898500862111287");

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '$deafen') {
    user.voice.setDeaf(true);
  }
});
```

However, if you instead want to deafen a mentioned member you could take this approach.

```js
var Discord  = require("discord.js");
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  let mentioned = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (message.content === '$deafen') {
    mentioned.voice.setDeaf(true);
  }
});
```

(On a side note I'd recommend the use of constants for your discord and client object so they may not be mutated)

`const Discord = require("discord.js");`